# AngularJS convert string date and integer time

Tags: angularjs

I have a string with a full date like this: `"2016/03/05 13:47:18 +0000"`.

I want covert it to `"2016-03-05"` or `"05-March-2016"` on Angular scope. I also have integer time `duration = 421471` which I want to convert to a time format like `"23:45"` or `"1 hour , 50 minute"`.

```
{{sound.created_at | date}} 

{{sound.duration}}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you look at moment? https://momentjs.com/ This lib does all the job anyome would need to do in JS and integrates well in AngularJs and Angular4

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: i need for angular  @bsoulier

Comment: https://github.com/urish/angular-moment as I said

Comment: Added proper answer to your question from my comment so that you can mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue please use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com) as very famous lib to deal everything about date in js.

To make it work well with Angularjs/4, please [have a look here](http://github.com/urish/angular-moment).